# What term defines the language specific to a time period?

Tags: single-word-requests

What term defines the language specific to a specific time period? Would you use *colloquial* or *vernacular*, or something else?

Comment: Have you looked up _vernacular_ and _colloquial_ to see if they applied?

Comment: Colloquially, you could say **slangism of [Time Period such as the 1800s, or Anglo-Saxon, someone's dynasty, etc]** since slang could change per time or culture, be it due to invasions or whatnot. Also, **Anachronistic language/words** might work if the language was being used in a different period(old one), though it doesn't by itself specificize to a particular time period. Every period has its own name(s) derived from historical, geographical, religious, and cultural reasons, so you just have to settle with the one you're looking for.

Comment: You want one term to label the language of a set period as *era-specific*, rather than different labels for different periods?

Answer (score 1):

You use adjectives or adjective-like terms to modify the name of the language and this is meant to characterize the language as a whole. "Colloquial" is a term that has to do with the register of a language and "vernacular" has to do with the language spoken in a particular region or group (in particular if not the official language), so these terms have nothing to do with periods¹. There are a multitude of extant terms for the English spoken in various periods; here are a few.

- Mid-twentieth Century English, Middle English, Victorian English, Elizabethan English, Late Old English, Early 20th century English, Edwardian English, 1960's English, etc.

Here are two  instances (provided by [**user Peter Shor**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/554839/what-term-defines-the-language-specific-to-a-time-period/554841?noredirect=1#comment1367087_554841)) in which the language is not named but is instead identified generically; in fact, "vernacular" is the term used for that identification.

- 19th century vernacular, Southern vernacular

¹ <sub>What I mean to say when I write "has nothing to do with 'periods"' is that "vernacular" can't be used to specify a period, what provides the information proper to the period is the modifier.</sub>

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use *vernacular* for periods, although you probably wouldn't use it for the proper, formal English of a given time period. See [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=19th+century+vernacular%2CSouthern+vernacular&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=5&direct_url=t1%3B%2C19th%20century%20vernacular%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSouthern%20vernacular%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What I mean to say when I write "has nothing to do with 'periods"' is that "vernacular" can't be used to specify a period, what provides the information proper to the period is the modifier.  I guess it could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this question is the adjective ***contemporary*** as applied to *language*. Per the OED, it means:

> 1. Belonging to the same era or period as another person, thing, or event; living, existing, or occurring together in a particular period; coexisting.

They present citations including these:

> - **2001**   *Hist. Today* Nov. 20/1  
>    Had large animals become extinct, and if so, had they once been contemporary with people?
> - **2015**   J. Rubenstein *First Crusade* ɪ. 2 
>     A contemporary historian named Guibert of Nogent (ca. 1060–ca. 1125) viewed the First Crusade as..‘a new path to salvation’.

So in the context of some particular historical time and place, whether that’s the nineteenth century in England or the seventeenth century in France, you could equally well speak of events there and then citing the *contemporary language* used by people in those times.